# Data size problem at Keras fitting with multi-input multi-output autoencoder

Tags: keras, callback, autoencoder

I try to build up a multi-input multi-output encoder for dense data representation. (The explanation for the architecture is that I wanted one common network to optimize for the numerical and the categorical data reconstruction in one.)

From my original data I produced a 28-column wide one-hot-encoded array for the categorical data and another 17-column wide normalized array for the numerical data:

```
m_cat_train.shape # (59768, 28)
m_cat_test.shape # (3146, 28)
m_num_train.shape # (59768, 17)
m_num_test.shape # (3146, 17)
```

My architecture:

```
cat_input = Input(shape=(m_cat.shape[1],))
num_input = Input(shape=(m_num.shape[1],))

cat_enc = Dense(16, activation='relu')(cat_input)
cat_enc = Dense(8, activation='relu')(cat_enc)

num_enc = Dense(16, activation='relu')(num_input)
num_enc = Dense(8, activation='relu')(num_enc)

bottleneck = concatenate([cat_enc, num_enc])

cat_dec = Dense(8, activation='relu')(bottleneck)
cat_dec = Dense(16, activation='relu')(cat_dec)
cat_output = Dense(m_cat.shape[1], activation='sigmoid', name="cat_output")(cat_dec)

num_dec = Dense(8, activation='relu')(bottleneck)
num_dec = Dense(16, activation='relu')(num_dec)
num_output = Dense(m_num.shape[1], activation='linear', name="num_output")(num_dec)

model = Model(inputs=[cat_input, num_input], 
              outputs =[cat_output, num_output], 
              name="autoencoder")
```

However, at training:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss={"cat_output" : "categorical_crossentropy", "num_output":"mse"},
              loss_weights={"cat_output": 1.0, "num_output": 1.0},
              metrics={"cat_output": 'accuracy', "num_output": 'accuracy'})

hist = model.fit([m_cat_train, m_num_train], [m_cat_test, m_num_test],
    batch_size=16,
    epochs=16,
    verbose=1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 59756, 59756
  y sizes: 3146, 3146
Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples.
```

What is the problem here? As far as I see the dimensions of the inputs and outputs are OK, how to interpret the error message? How comes 'cardinality' here?

**Bonus question related**: how to define an `EarlyStopping` callback for fitting which somehow combines the two metrics into one as stopping condition?

```
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

earlyStopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_accuracy', 
    restore_best_weights=True,
    mode='max')
```

Which `val_accuracy` is observed in the above code?

Comment: `x` and `y` need to have the same dimension size for the first (batch size) value. Your `x` and `y` don't have the same values there: 59756 vs 3146.

Comment: Or 28 vs 17 *charlim*